# Помочь с option

Tags: php, javascript

Есть код:

```html
<li><label>Провайдер</label><select name="form_provider" id="type" size="1" ><option value=""'.($row['provider']==''?' selected="selected"':'').'>Отсутствует</option>
<option value=\'California\''.($row['provider']!=''?' selected="selected"':'').'>California.Ua</option></select></li>
```

При выборе option California в базу данных заносится "California", а если выбрать option "Отсутствует" то в базу заносится просто пустота, ячейка становится пустой, необходимо чтобы заносился текст "Отсутствует", без понятия как реализовать, помогите, пожалуйста...

Comment: А разве не нужно и первому option указать конкретное value, оно же и будет отправляться?

Comment: @Frigoris пробовал, но так потом показывается в админке не то что в ячейке прописано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем коде полученное значение сравнивается с пустотой, вероятно нужно сравнивать со значением каждого элемента списка.
И, как верно заметил [Frigoris](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/287395/frigoris), каждый элемент должен иметь установленное значение value. Если при отправке записывается неверное значение - проверьте соответствие кодировки в БД и на странице.

```
<li>
<label>Провайдер</label>
<select name="form_provider" id="type" size="1" >
<option value=\'Отсутствует\''.($row['provider']=='Отсутствует'?' selected ':'').'>Отсутствует</option>
<option value=\'California.Ua\''.($row['provider']=='California.Ua'?' selected ':'').'>California.Ua</option>
</select>
</li>
```